# All sets with groups of similar objects

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations

I have $i$ types of objects, and I want to build sets with $j$ ($1 \le j \le n$) objects from them ($i \le n$). The position of objects in the set is immaterial.

For example, for $i=2$ (i.e. I have two types of objects: $a$ and $b$) and $n=4$. Then:

for $j=1$:
Two sets: $\{a\}, \{b\}$

for $j=2$:
Three sets: $\{a, a\}, \{a, b\}, \{b, b\}$

for $j=3$:
Four sets: $\{a, a, a\}, \{a, a, b\}, \{a, b, b\}, \{b, b, b\}$

for $j=4$:
Five sets: $\{a, a, a, a\}, \{a, a, a, b\}, \{a, a, b, b\}, \{a, b, b, b\}, \{b, b, b, b\}$

How can I come to a formula for this type of arrangements? for any $i$ and $n$?

Comment: What is $n$? Do you mean the number of objects is $n$ and that there are $ i$ types of objects whose number sum to $n$. (Or equivalently, there is an upper bound for number of objects of each type.)

Comment: Actually $i$ can be at most equal to $n$, when there is only one object of each type. I think the stars and bars formula you suggested is exactly what I want. My final goal is to calculate the order of a series of computations. So, I think for $i=2$, it will be of $O(n)$, for $i=3$ it will be of $O(n^2)$, and ... for $i=n$ it will be of $O(n^{n-1})$.

Comment: When you are assuming $j=n$, when $i=O(1)$, then the order of the number you want is exactly $O(n^i)$. But when $i$ is comarable with $n$, need to use stirling's formula to approximate. When $i=n$, the order should be about $2^{2n}/\sqrt(n)$

Comment: So let me be precise. I have a dynamic programming algorithm with $n$ stages. At each stage $1 \le j \le n$, it will need ${i+j-1} \choose j$ states. So, since the worst case arises for $j=n$, the complexity would be of $n*{{i+n-1} \choose n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just star-and-bar argument.

SUppose we have objects of $i$ types, and for any $k \le i$, there are $a_k$ objects in the set with $j$ objects.

This suffices to evaluate number of solutions of $a_1+a_2+...+a_i=j$,
the number of solutions is exactly ${i+j-1}\choose{j}$. (given by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics))